# Form input shown by jquery is not posting on submit - codeigniter

Tags: jquery, html, codeigniter, input, tags

I have a form in view in which some input fields are dynamically shown using Jquery while choosing some select input fields.

Each form input fields are wrapped in separate classes thus the Jquery uses the class names to show those input fields.

The thing is, some dynamically input field is not submitting value to the controller by preventing entire form from submitting. But some works fine. When i remove the input fields(along with wrapped class) that making this issue, then it works fine. If i keep that wrapped class by removing the input field only then also its not working. That means its working only if the entire class having the input field is removed.

Below is the dynamically generated input field with wrapped class which works fine.

```html
<div class="form-group *popin-input-price*" style="display:none">
  <label class="control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12" for="popin-input-price">Enter price value<span class="required text-red">*</span>
  </label>
  <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">

      <input type="text" id="popin-input-price" name="popin-input-price" required="required" class="form-control col-md-7 col-xs-12">
  </div>
</div>
```

Below is one of the dynamically generated input field with wrapped div which preventing form submitting.

```html
<div class="form-group *popin-input-price-btwn*" style="display:none">
    <label class="control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12" for="popin-input-price-btwn">Enter price range<span class="required text-red">*</span>
    </label>
    <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-4">
      <input type="text" name="popin-input-price-btwn[]" required="required" class="form-control col-md-7 col-xs-12">
    </div>
</div>
```

Also when i changed the wrapped class of input element causing the issue(popin-input-price-btwn) with the wrapped class of a working input field(popin-input-price), then that input field also works, data submits.

So it seems like the issue is not related with input, but the class wrapped the input field and i am not sure about it. Any one kindly help.

Comment: Are you removing the required="required" attribute when you display a block? That could explain why its not submitting. Also if you are using CI form validation - I would check if the fields are required when in fact they may not come through in the post.

Comment: @Antony, thank you for your time. No, i am not removing 'required' when displaying the blocks containing input field.